# Is there any way to use Material UI select in react-flags-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, npm-package

I want to set default country for which the number can be added in the application. For this purpose, I am using [react-flags-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flags-select) npm package.
Now the problem is that I am using React Material UI everywhere else in the application and I want UI similar to that for this dropdown as well.

In case where the number is entered I am using [material-ui-phone-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-phone-number) which is built on material UI but I cannot find any package like that in case of Country Code only.

Is there any other npm package like this or is there any way to convert this flags dropdown to Material UI dropdown?

I am attaching pictures as well for better explanation of my problem.

- react-flags-select (which I want to look like Material UI)
  [image]
- material-ui-phone-number (Phone number input which is already like Material UI)
  [image]

Any help would be really appreciated!